# Changing chapter font size and apply the font to Introduction

Tags: chapters

I have two problems while working on this code :

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\@makechapterhead}[1]{
  \vspace*{50\p@}
  {%
    \parindent \z@ \raggedright
    \setmainfont{Book Antiqua}
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \if@mainmatter
        \large \bfseries \@chapapp \space \thechapter \par
        \nobreak \vskip 20\p@
        \setmainfont{Adine Kirnberg Regular}
      \fi
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty \@M \Huge \bfseries #1\par
    \nobreak \vskip 40\p@
  }}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter*{Introduction}
Some text in intro.
\chapter{This is the first chapter}
Some text in chapter 1.
\chapter{This is the second chapter}
Some text in chapter 2.
\end{document}
```

I need another way to set size to 38p because `\Huge` is not big enough for the font Adine Kirnberg Regular (found here http://www.1001fonts.com/adine-kirnberg-font.html), and `\chapter*{Introduction}`doesnt have the same font as the others. I gave up on using `titling` because I also change how the chapter are numbered.

Comment: is `\fontsize{3cm}{3.5cm}\selectfont`  big enough?

Comment: `\@makechapterhead` is for numbered headings in `book.cls` you will find `\@makeschapterhead` for stared (un-numbered) chapters which you can redefine to match.

Comment: Can I use the same code ?

Comment: you should not be using `\setmainfont` within these heading macros that is for setting the default font for the whole document not to select a local font for this heading

Comment: well no because for unnumbered headings you don't want to use `\thechapter` which is a number. just make matching changes to the two commands

Comment: Someone gave me the chapter code, I dont understand it well enough to change it. Size worked, I used `\fontsize{38}{42}\selectfont`

Comment: Never mind: It worked. Simply deleted the ifs. Can you write an answer or do you want me to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\@makechapterhead` is for numbered headings in book.cls you will find `\@makeschapterhead` for stared (un-numbered) chapters which you can redefine to match.

You can use any size font `\fontsize{38}{42}\selectfont` for 38pt on a 42pt baseline for example.

Answer (score 0):

I am posting the code for any case

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\makeatletter % changing font and size for \chapter*{}
\renewcommand*{\@makeschapterhead}[1]{
  \vspace*{50\p@}
  {%
    \parindent \z@ \raggedright
    \setmainfont{Adine Kirnberg Regular}
    \interlinepenalty \@M \fontsize{38}{42}\selectfont \bfseries #1\par
    \nobreak \vskip 40\p@
  }}
\makeatother

\makeatletter % changing font and size for \chapter{}
\renewcommand*{\@makechapterhead}[1]{
  \vspace*{50\p@}
  {%
    \parindent \z@ \raggedright
    \setmainfont{Book Antiqua}
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \if@mainmatter
        \large \bfseries \@chapapp \space \thechapter \par
        \nobreak \vskip 20\p@
        \setmainfont{Adine Kirnberg Regular}
      \fi
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty \@M \fontsize{38}{42}\selectfont \bfseries #1\par
    \nobreak \vskip 40\p@
  }}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter*{Introduction}
Some text in intro.
\chapter{This is the first chapter}
Some text in chapter 1.
\chapter{This is the second chapter}
Some text in chapter 2.
\end{document}
```

I don't know how to set the font locally for Open Type so I keep using `\setmainfont{}`